# How to get "name" value in a response in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, postman

I'm trying to make HTTP POST request in postman. In my project, I'm using the express framework from Nodejs. In postman, when I post {
  "name": 'course2',}, in my response, I can only see its id {"id":2} .I would like to see the id and the name in the response - {"id":2,"name":"course2"}

I hardcoded one course with its "id" and "name". However, when I try to make an HTTP post request and create a new course with its name and id, in my response I only get the id and not the name of the course.

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const courses = [{id : 1, name : 'course1'}];

app.post('/api/courses/', (req, res) => {
    const course = {
        id: courses.length + 1,
        name: req.body.name
    };
    courses.push(course);
    res.send(course);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}...`));
```

I would like to see the id and the name in the response - `{"id":2,"name":"course2"}`

Comment: Are you sure req.body.name is not undefined? Because if it is you will get just id in response.

Comment: Make sure that you are sending data as JSON in postman

Comment: You will probably also need to use the `body-parser` module with your express server.

Answer (score 1):

In postman send data as a JSON format like :

`{
  "name":"Petra",
 }`

select the Json format before send!

Answer (score 0):

To make this code work you will have to select body raw as in postman as shown in attached image.

You should add this line to handle x-www-form-urlencoded values:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

[image: Postman snapshot]